# Why is $(e_n)$ not a basis for $\ell_\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, schauder-basis

Let $(e_n)$ (where $ e_n $ has a 1 in the $n$-th place and zeros otherwise) be unit  standard vectors of $\ell_\infty$.

Why is $(e_n)$ not a basis for $\ell_\infty$?

Thanks.

Comment: basis in what sense?

Comment: Because $(1, 1, 1, \dots , 1, \dots )$ is not spanned by those.

Comment: I suspect the meaning here is ***not*** a Hamel basis.

Comment: @Schauder basis

Answer (score 12):

There are basically two things to note here. First you need to understand what it means for a set to be a basis of an infinite dimensional normed space. In your context, I am all but certain that this means that it is a Schauder basis, which is a linearly independent set such that the set of all finite linear combinations of members of the set is dense in the space. The other kind of basis is a Hamel basis, which is an "algebraic" basis, i.e. a linearly independent set such that the set of all finite linear combinations of members spans the space.

For $\ell^\infty$, any member of the set of finite linear combinations of $e_n$ is eventually zero. But $[1,1,1,\dots] \in \ell^\infty$ but it is at least $1$ away from any sequence which is eventually zero.

Comment: That last line is nailing it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In what manner?

Comment: @Amitai: In the manner that makes people pull their socks over their right pant leg. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, totally, that's exactly what it got me doing.

Comment: People still wear pants?

Comment: @Matt: Not everyone can be Walter White and stand in the middle of the desert with their tighty whities.

Comment: @Ian, I am sorry, but I could not understand about your last paragraph. The Schauder basis means that all elements of the set can be a infinite linear combination (with uniqueness) of the elements of the basis, isn't? So, $(1,1,1,\cdots)=\sum^\infty_{j=1}e_j$ and I cannot understand why is not a Schauder basis... However, I can understand the proofs about $l^\infty$ be not separable. I just cannot understand why explain that this is not a basis. Many thanks.

Comment: @Na'omi I explained that above: a Schauder basis requires that the span of the finite linear combinations be dense. One reason why this requirement is essential is that in fact $\sum_{j=1}^\infty e_j$ is not a well defined sum in $\ell^\infty$ because $v_N=\sum_{j=1}^N e_j$ has no limit in $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: @Ian, I think I finally understood. It seems to me a little counterintuitive, but with infinite... Somethings are counterintuitive anyway... Thank you very much, Ian, for your attention and help.

Comment: @Na'omi It will help to drop the notion that infinite sums are really any different from general limits. $\sum_{j=1}^\infty e_j$ is a meaningless symbol in the $\ell^\infty$ setting because $x_n=\sum_{j=1}^n e_j$ is not Cauchy in $\ell^\infty$. That is easy to see because $\| x_n-x_m \|_{\ell^\infty}=1$ for all $n \neq m$. That's all there is to it. The only question is whether this normed vector space type analysis is the right way to look at $\ell^\infty$ in the first place.

Comment: @Ian right! Many thanks once again!

Answer (score 6):

A Schauder basis is a dense countable subset. But there does not exist any dense countable subset in $\ell^\infty$.

Let us prove that no such set can exist:

By contradiction, assume that $D$ was a dense countable subset of $\ell^\infty$. Now consider the set $S = \{s\mid s_n \in \{0,1\}\}$, that is, all sequences only consisting of $0$ and $1$.

If we consider balls of radius ${1\over 3}$ around each $s$ then in every such ball there will have to be a $d$ in $D$ since $D$ is dense. But $S$ is uncountable therefore this cannot be the case. Hence $\ell^\infty$ cannot contain a dense countable subset.

In particular, $e_n$ cannot be a Schauder basis.

Comment: I'm a little late with this answer but I thought I'd add my 5 cents anyway... hope it helps!

Comment: Technically a Schauder basis itself is not dense, but its rational span would be, while still being countable.